# For Loop to check if any rows have a specfic set of values

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a for-loop to check if any my rows contain a specific set of values.  I already know you can simply apply a function to remove the set from the dataframe, but I want to know how to run a for-loop as well. Thanks!

This is my dataframe:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 12, ncol = 3))
df$V1 <- c('1','1','2','3','3','3','4','4','5','5','5','5')
df$V2 <- c('CCC','BBB','AAA','AAA','EEE','BBB','AAA','DDD','EEE','EEE','BBB','CCC')
df$V3 <- c(100,90,80,85,66,98,62,74,56,85,77,66)
colnames(df) <- c('ID','Secondary_ID','Number')
```

Grouping the Data so there is only 1 unique ID per row

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_2 <- df%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  summarise(Key_s = paste0(Secondary_ID, collapse = ','))%>%
  separate(Key_s, into = c('1','2','3','4'))
```

I know that you can remove the specific set like this:

```
remove_this <- c('BBB','CCC')

df_remove <- apply(df_2, 1, function(x) !any(x %in% remove_this))
final_dataframe <- df_2[df_remove,]
```

I'm trying to run a for-loop which creates another column called output, and if it contains the specific set than "Yes" else "No".

Something like this:

```
output <- as.character(nrow(df_2))

for(i in 1:nrow(df_2)){
  if(df_2[i,] %in% remove_this){
    df_2$output <- "Yes"
  }else{df_2$output <- "No"}
}
```

Comment: This is a simple indexing trick and you already have computed the index: `df_2$output <- "No"; df_2$output[df_remove] <- "Yes"`. Oh, I find the name `df_remove` misleading, could I suggest `df_keep`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas How would you go about writing this without the df_remove, I want to write the for_loop as if I never wrote the df_remove.

Comment: The indexing method is by far the fastest. Why would you want another method? Can you explain the reason for it? (Maybe the actual code is more complicated...)

Comment: @RuiBarradas For Practice sake, and I want to know how to do things more than 1 way =).

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the test to see if the contents of `remove_this` are in the row.

```
df_2$output <- NA  # initialize the column
for(i in 1:nrow(df_2)){
    df_2$output[i] <- ifelse(all(remove_this %in% df_2[i,]), 'Yes', 'No')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a for loop:

```
remove_this <- c('BBB','CCC')
df_remove <- apply(df_2, 1, function(x) !any(x %in% remove_this))

df_2 %>% 
  mutate(output = c("No", "Yes")[df_remove + 1L])
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 6
>   ID    `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   output
>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
> 1 1     CCC   BBB   NA    NA    No    
> 2 2     AAA   NA    NA    NA    Yes   
> 3 3     AAA   EEE   BBB   NA    No    
> 4 4     AAA   DDD   NA    NA    Yes   
> 5 5     EEE   EEE   BBB   CCC   No
> ```

The "trick" is to convert the logical values `FALSE` and `TRUE` of `df_remove` into integer indices which are used to subset the vector `c("No", "Yes")`.